# Checking object fields based on string identifiers

Tags: java, oop, object

I have an object with fields of different types, mainly String, Float, Integer.

I need to write a method to check an **array** of such objects, whether specific fields, identified by a certain string identifiers, are not null and not empty.

For example, I have the following fields:

```
String field1;
Integer field2;
String field3;
```

and an identifiers:

```
String IDENTIFIER_FIELD_1 = "IDENTIFIER_1";
String IDENTIFIER_FIELD_2 = "IDENTIFIER_2";
```

If I pass an `ArrayList<String>` with `IDENTIFIER_FIELD_1` to my method, I want to check `field1` only, if I pass an `ArrayList<String>` with `IDENTIFIER_FIELD_1` and `IDENTIFIER_FIELD_2`, I would like to check both `field2` and `field2`.

Is there any effective way in Java to do such checks for an **array** of objects? The only solution I come up with is to check every field using string comparison but that wouldn't be effective at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bit of reflection, it might be an "overkill" tho. There is a flaw in this method, you need to know the exact names of variables, but I believe you have them.

```
public class TestObject {

//Some fields.
private int firstInt;
private int secondInt;
private String firstString;

public TestObject(int firstInt, int secondInt, String firstString) { 
    this.firstInt = firstInt;
    this.secondInt = secondInt;
    this.firstString = firstString;
}

public void checkForNulls(String... fieldsToSearch) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    boolean isValid = true;

    //Here we retrieve all the fields we need from our class.
    for (String fieldName : fieldsToSearch) {
        //Here is the method to get a field by name.
        try {
            Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);

            //Change access modifier so we can get the value.
            field.setAccessible(true);

            //Get the field value of this instance.
            if (field.get(this) == null) {
                isValid = false;
                System.out.println("Fix him! Field " + field.getName() + " equals null!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //There can be no field with such name, you need to do something here.
        }
    }

    if (isValid) {
        System.out.println("This objects fields are fine.");
    }
}
}
```

And now the main method:

```
public class Test {
//Names of the fields, you actually need to know them.
public static final String FIRST_INT_INDENTIFIER = "firstInt";
public static final String SECOND_INT_INDENTIFIER = "secondInt";
public static final String FIRST_STRING_INDENTIFIER = "firstString";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestObject[] testArray = new TestObject[10];

    //Fill the array with some objects.
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        testArray[i] = new TestObject(i, i * 2, "Number: " + i);

        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            testArray[i] = new TestObject(i, i * 2, null);
        }
    }

    //Check the array of our objects.
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        try {
            testArray[i].checkForNulls(FIRST_INT_INDENTIFIER, FIRST_STRING_INDENTIFIER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Some exception handling
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This looks like the right solution but I'm not sure if I will be able to effectively use it on array of objects (without having to create `List<Field>` every time).

Comment: Well, you could check the value of the field and perform any actions in the first for loop, without adding it to List<Field> (when you retrieve the field by name). Adding the fields to list to immediately use them in for each loop was indeed a misconception by me ;) I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use contains method like:

```
if (mylist.contains("field1") && myList.contains("field2")) {
    System.out.println("Found both identifier");
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Then can you explain it in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would put a method inside the object, something like:

```
public boolean isPopulated(String key){ // or int key if you're more interested in efficiency than clarity

    switch(key){
        case "field1":
            if (field1 != null && !field1.equals("")) return true;
            return false;
            break;
        case "field2":
            etc
```

That way you can define for each field what 'empty' means.

Then stating the obvious, your checking method would look like (assuming you went with Integer fields rather than Strings)

```
public boolean areAllPopulated(ArrayList<MyObject> objects, ArrayList<Integer> fields) {
    for (Integer field : fields){
        for (MyObject object : objects){
            if (object.isPopulated(field) == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you're worried about the cost of String comparison, you could create a HashMap of fieldNames to fieldIntegers somewhere and convert the ArrayList of 
Strings to an ArrayList of Integers at the start of the checking method, which would save you most of the String comparison penalty.